# How can I hibernate and switch between Windows 7 and Windows 10 on different SSDs?

Tags: windows, multi-boot, grub, hibernate, bootloader

I've got 2 OS, 3 drives:

1. `ssd1` with Windows 10
2. `ssd2` with Windows 7, plus `hdd`

So here're a couple of questions:

1. How can I quickly switch between these OSes, using hibernation and rebooting?
   I heard I need to do something with bootloader.
2. How can I ensure that `ssd2` and `hdd` are never visible / accessible from Windows 10 (for security reasons)? Neither from Admin, nor from apps with Admin rights. I don't want to encrypt my drives, or use virtualization. And of course I don't want to physically disconnect the drives. Is there another way?

Comment: Try:  https://superuser.com/questions/419186/how-should-i-set-up-my-dual-boot-so-that-i-can-hibernate-the-secondary-os    If you want to hibernate and use a different OS while Windows is hibernated you must not put the Windows bootloader first.
If the Windows bootloader is first, the very first thing it does before showing the menu is check for a hibernated OS.  ... Now if GRUB is the MBR boot menu and is configured to chainload BOOTMGR or boot into Linux, ...   Read the solution

Comment: Thank you @John, and as regards isolating drives between OSes, what do you think, is it enough to hide disks in bootloader or should I opt for a SATA Power Splitter Adapter Cable that will help me to simply power off sensitive drives while switching OSes? I have some malware-like software in my Windows 10 that I need for my work, unfortunately (27/69 detections on virustotal).

Comment: You asked "Is it enough to hide disks in bootloader?"  I think it is. Make sure systems have good passwords and then for most situations, this should suffice.

Comment: But passwords are totally useless when there's administrative access to disk, aren't they?

Comment: If other people have access, that could be a concern. But most people would try to start the system.

Comment: Also some other administrator normally cannot get access to USER folders under a different name.

Comment: AFAIK, admin (app with admin rights) from other OS can access *everything*, unless disk is not encrypted. I think I'll use both physical disconnect as well as hiding disks with NeoGrub (in case I forget to do the former).

Comment: It takes a bit of effort for a random admin to get to user folders but your idea is sound.