# Windows: Do not change UEFI boot mode when hibernating

Tags: uefi, windows-11, hibernate, thinkpad

I am running a Lenovo T14s with UEFI dual boot. Mostly Windows 10/11 and Linux. My current workflow for fast switching is to hibernate an OS and use the boot device menu (F12) to boot/resume the other one. Not quite as nice as two separate devices or VM, but as some tasks do not work with VMs and multiple devices are not quite as mobile, this workflow suits my requirements best.

When hibernating Linux all works as expected: State is dumped to disk, device turns off, I can press F12 when turning back on and boot/resume Windows (or Linux).
When hibernating Windows it isn't quite as smooth: It also saves its state and turns off, however it also reconfigures UEFI for some kind of automatic resume mode. When turning on UEFI won't accept F12 but directly resume Windows.

I can work around this by turning on the device, turning it off by holding the power button before Windows loads and turning it back on again. Now F12 works and I can choose which OS I want to boot/resume. This doesn't seem to affect Windows, as I can use Linux, hibernate it and resume Windows at a later time without any problems.

Any ideas how to stop Windows from hogging my boot process when hibernating? Fast boot is already off.

Comment: Windows fast boot or UEFI fast boot? Those are two different parameters.

Comment: seems [this](https://superuser.com/a/421040/504075) may help - although, maybe not - it mentions MBR boot